# How can I pass data through a DragDrop event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I have very little experience making my own events. I'm currently using forms and controls to handle events, so I'm trying to stick to the WinForm way of dealing with events.

WinForm controls already have their own events. Since events are made with a certain delegate type, I have to match the delegate signature in the methods I use to handle what goes on during an event. As far as I can tell, this means I have to take in two parameters in my event handlers: a source `Object` and an `EventArgs`.

I'm trying to figure out how to pass various information between controls through `DragDrop` related events. I've been able to find various code snippets online for different situations, but I'd like to have a better understanding of how the information is actually passed around.

When it comes to `DragDrop` events in particular, it seems my information will be passed through a `DataObject`. That, in turn, is passed as a parameter to the `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` method.

This is where my understanding starts to diminish. In most examples I've seen, it looks like some sort of data format is specified. The data format itself is of type string. Usually the data format is passed along with the data into the `DataObject`.

What is this data format doing? Is it just showing the type of the data involved? I've seen examples where the data format was tested, and various actions took place depending on what the data format had been. Couldn't you just do a typeof(YourData) to check for the type? I don't understand how a data format is useful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741842.aspx

In the above link, the first example shows a `DataObject` being created with no data format  being specified. It explains that the data format is automatically chosen and that your object is converted by default.

Can you just pass any object into the `DataObject`? Then when the `DragDrop` event takes place on the target control, can that control access the methods and fields of the object passed? Or will the object be converted into some other form by the `DataObject`? How about various structures?

I've also done some drag and dropping from a Windows explorer icon to my forms. I was able to get the icon's file path with some example code I found. It also used a data format.

```
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}
```

**SUMMARY:**
I'm trying to get an understanding of how data is passed through WinForm events. I don't understand some of what I've seen in various `DragDrop` examples. I understand that data is somehow stored in various formats, and that there is a way to extract that data. I don't understand what a data format is used for. I don't understand exactly what sorts of data can be transferred through a `DataObject`. My understanding of `EventArgs` in general is fairly lacking.

Feel free to comment on anything I've mentioned here. If I stated something incorrectly, point it out. Anything that will help me understand this subject better is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I decided to explain where I plan to go with this. Maybe someone can use what I'm trying to do as a way to explain some of what I asked.

I have a form that contains a certain type of control. I'm trying to make the placement of the controls highly customizable and dynamic. Whenever another control is added to the form by the user, every control is automatically repositioned to keep things orderly.

I'm currently trying to allow the user to drag a control around the Form to resposition it. Wherever the user decides to drop the control, all of the other controls will move out of the way to make room for the move control.

If I'm going to be able to move the dragged control and all the other controls on the form properly, I need to be able to get certain information from the dragged control. The main data that would need to be passed through the events would take the form of a Location property that uses a `System.Drawing.Point` structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to give you an idea of how it's done.

First drop two panels on a Form, and set their colors to two different colors.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    panel1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseDown);
    panel2.AllowDrop = true;
    panel2.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(panel2_DragEnter);
    panel2.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(panel2_DragDrop);
}

void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    panel1.DoDragDrop(panel1, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

void panel2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetData(typeof(Panel)) != null) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

void panel2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Panel p = sender as Panel;//Not needed in this case. Could just write panel2.
    Panel dropped = (Panel)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Panel));
    dropped.Location = p.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    p.Controls.Add(dropped);
}
```

Then drag panel1 onto panel2.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem should not be solved using drag&drop. Drag&drop is meant as a way for *multiple applications* to exchange data. If the data you are dragging is only meaningful for the current process, don't use drag&drop.

You can just use a field (for example, a field on the instance of the containing Form) to store all the data you need.

Just to say the obvious: Drag&drop is not a way to drag around controls. You need a lot of custom logic for that, anyway. It's not like the built-in features of dnd would help you here.

Comment: When you say that DnD is not the way, are you specifically talking about DnD as a means to moving data? When trying to think of how I could use fields in different classes to keep up with various information, I can't think of a way around using drag events. Also, you mentioned DnD should be used between applications. Could this explain the reason for having data formats in the DragEventArgs? Within my own application, the data formats seemed a little strange to me.

Comment: Yes, the data formats are a standardized way to exchange data between apps (Text, Html, FileList, ...). Writing a custom format will help you nothing because it won't be meaningful for other apps.